# Qt link static built lib

Tags: windows, qt, static-libraries, qmake

I have a project targeted as **lib** and another one as an **app**.

First project successfully builds as a **static** and as a **dynamic** (shared) lib.

Second project successfully links a **dynamic** lib, but it can't link a **static** one.
Many error messages like `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol` appear.

app.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += static link_prl ordered
DEFINES += QT_NODLL
QT += core gui network xml

...

# --- LINK QUAZIP LIB SHARED ---

#LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Qt/quazip/build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_shared-Debug/quazip/debug) -lquazip
#PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$quote(C:/Qt/quazip/build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_shared-Debug/quazip/debug/quazip.lib)

# --- LINK QUAZIP LIB STATIC ---

LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Qt/quazip/build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_static-Release/quazip/release) -lquazip
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$quote(C:/Qt/quazip/build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_static-Release/quazip/release/quazip.lib)
```

Directories content:

```
 Directory of C:\Qt\quazip\build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_shared-Debug\quazip\debug

04.04.2013  11:01    <DIR>          .                                           
04.04.2013  11:01    <DIR>          ..                                          
04.04.2013  11:01           188 498 JlCompress.obj                              
04.04.2013  11:01             2 484 moc_quagzipfile.cpp                         
04.04.2013  11:01            43 994 moc_quagzipfile.obj                         
04.04.2013  11:01             2 501 moc_quaziodevice.cpp                        
04.04.2013  11:01            44 026 moc_quaziodevice.obj                        
04.04.2013  11:01             2 467 moc_quazipfile.cpp                          
04.04.2013  11:01            62 441 moc_quazipfile.obj                          
04.04.2013  11:01            40 936 qioapi.obj                                  
04.04.2013  11:01            24 586 quaadler32.obj                              
04.04.2013  11:01            24 554 quacrc32.obj                                
04.04.2013  11:01            73 276 quagzipfile.obj                             
04.04.2013  11:01            69 745 quaziodevice.obj                            
04.04.2013  11:01           188 928 quazip.dll                                  
04.04.2013  11:01            40 067 quazip.exp                                  
04.04.2013  11:01           999 808 quazip.ilk                                  
04.04.2013  11:01               381 quazip.intermediate.manifest                
04.04.2013  11:01            65 678 quazip.lib                                  
04.04.2013  11:01           156 746 quazip.obj                                  
04.04.2013  11:01         1 166 336 quazip.pdb                                  
04.04.2013  11:01           259 653 quazipdir.obj                               
04.04.2013  11:01           117 317 quazipfile.obj                              
04.04.2013  11:01            47 039 quazipfileinfo.obj                          
04.04.2013  11:01            57 489 quazipnewinfo.obj                           
04.04.2013  11:01            35 483 unzip.obj                                   
04.04.2013  11:01            34 526 zip.obj                                     
              25 File(s)      3 748 959 bytes                                   
               2 Dir(s)  17 125 515 264 bytes free

 Directory of C:\Qt\quazip\build-quazip-0.5.1-Qt_4_8_3_static-Release\quazip\release

04.04.2013  12:46    <DIR>          .                                               
04.04.2013  12:46    <DIR>          ..                                              
04.04.2013  12:46         1 457 363 JlCompress.obj                                  
04.04.2013  12:46             2 484 moc_quagzipfile.cpp                             
04.04.2013  12:46         1 084 653 moc_quagzipfile.obj                             
04.04.2013  12:46             2 501 moc_quaziodevice.cpp                            
04.04.2013  12:46         1 084 461 moc_quaziodevice.obj                            
04.04.2013  12:46             2 467 moc_quazipfile.cpp                              
04.04.2013  12:46         1 199 125 moc_quazipfile.obj                              
04.04.2013  12:46         1 084 170 qioapi.obj                                      
04.04.2013  12:46           279 307 quaadler32.obj                                  
04.04.2013  12:46           279 270 quacrc32.obj                                    
04.04.2013  12:46         1 115 174 quagzipfile.obj                                 
04.04.2013  12:46         1 108 222 quaziodevice.obj                                
04.04.2013  12:46        14 977 872 quazip.lib                                      
04.04.2013  12:46         1 246 009 quazip.obj                                      
04.04.2013  12:46               801 quazip.prl                                      
04.04.2013  12:46         1 357 090 quazipdir.obj                                   
04.04.2013  12:46         1 246 159 quazipfile.obj                                  
04.04.2013  12:46         1 121 490 quazipfileinfo.obj                              
04.04.2013  12:46         1 134 685 quazipnewinfo.obj                               
04.04.2013  12:46            56 712 unzip.obj                                       
04.04.2013  12:46            59 090 zip.obj                                         
              21 File(s)     29 899 105 bytes                                       
               2 Dir(s)  17 123 479 552 bytes free
```

As I understand, **qmake** wants a dll to link to it.
How can I tell it I want to build a static app and let it look for externals inside a static built lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link QuaZip statically needs 
`CONFIG += staticlib`
in your qmake file.

Or make sure, that `QUAZIP_STATIC` is defined before you actually include any QuaZip header from your application.

Comment: TEMPLATE = app
    CONFIG += static +staticlib link_prl ordered
    DEFINES += QT_NODLL
    QT += core gui network xml
Nothing changed.

Comment: From official docs: Compile it as a static library using CONFIG += staticlib qmake option. QUAZIP_STATIC is defined automatically by qmake in this case.

And it's for a QuaZip project. Not for app that use qua zip.lib

Comment: Just added DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC to **app** project. Thanks a lot!